# Show only 2 commands in the menu bar in Lwuit or Native J2ME

Tags: java-me, menu, lwuit, command-behaviors

I added 2 commands to my form in lwuit.

```
form.addCommand(test);
form.setBackCommand(exitCommand);
```

I changed the command behavior to COMMAND_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE, so i can show the status, and my commands appear at the bottom too, but they appear exit at the right ..and test Command in the middle.
I want to show only 2 commands layout in the menu bar, Exit on the right and options list that contains test on the left.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about LWUIT since I've never used it, but with native JavaME you sadly have no control of this. It is the individual device that decides where to place the commands.

You can move them around by changing the priority parameter, and you may be able to achieve an acceptable result that way, but only on some devices. The same code will give a different result on other devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i must find a way to do that. Can i remove those commands?and build a new custom bar.

Answer (score 1):

First get the back `Command` and remove it. After this, add the exit `Command` like a standard `Command`with addCommand. Try this, if this doesn´t work we can try something else.

Comment: Ok i'll try it,but how can i get the J2ME Native Back Command, for lwuit i used  form.removeCommand(form.getMenuBar().getBackCommand());
But i must remove the Native one.

Comment: Jmunoz,,thank you for your help, but i guess form.getback command will get the lwuit one ,,,so it will not be removed from the menu..:(

Comment: it takes the default back Command...are you using a custom back command?

http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Form.html#getBackCommand()

Comment: I'm using this form.setBackCommand(exitCommand);
As i said before..it is not custom..but i think since i changed the Command Behavior to Native..this will not take an effect

Comment: So i did the fowlloing.
 form.removeCommand(form.getBackCommand());
        form.addCommand(test);
        form.addCommand(exitCommand);
I got an option command holding the 2 other commands..

Comment: The same Result..
form.removeAllCommands();
        form.addCommand(test);
        form.addCommand(exitCommand);

Comment: Do something similar with the MenuBar object... http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/MenuBar.html